# Making visual elements in objective - c

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, user-interface, dynamic

I'm new to objective-c and trying to figure out how to create a class which would make an object like this: [image]
But I want it to be a class so I can make multiples of them and put them in a list so the user can make as many of them as they want. Could someone point me towards a tutorial or something to help me? in XAML I would have just declared a canvas and made UI elements within the canvas, but I cant seem to figure out how to create UI elements in objective-c. :C

Comment: Are you building the UI with Storyboards, with XIBs, or programmatically?

Comment: If you want many of them, then you might want to use a UITableView, and your visual element would be a custom UITableViewCell. You could make that in the storyboard or a xib file..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a XIB file to create a template for a reusable UI Element or you could use storyboards to design your app, although it sounds like for your case XIBs fit best.

[This](http://michiganlabs.com/xibs-nibs-ios7-and-xcode5/#.VOJ6xGRVhBc) seems like a recent and well written tutorial you can use.